# Cannot exec() Python script from within entry_points script installed via pip and setuptools

Tags: python, pip, exec, setuptools, entry-point

I followed [these](https://go.chriswarrick.com/entry_points) instructions for creating a `setup.py` file that would install a Python "executable" script. This is my project's structure:

```
pkgexec/
  setup.py
  pkgexec/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    core.py
```

As per the instructions, the `__main__.py`'s `main()` method is an entry point in `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="pkgexec",
    version="0.2.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={ "console_scripts": ["pkgexec = pkgexec.__main__:main"]},
)
```

I installed the package from within the `pkgexec/` directory, by running `pip install -e .`.

Until this point, everything works as expected.

What *doesn't* work is executing Python scripts via this "executable" entry  point. You see, the whole aim of this package is to run Python scripts that import a bunch of stuff from the package, e.g. `script.py` uses functionality from the `pkgexec` package and is "ran" through the `pkgexec` "executable":

```
pkgexec script.py -v arg1 arg2
```

Here is the simplified version of `__main__.py`:

```py
import argparse
import sys

from pkgexec import some_stuff

def main(args=None):
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('script', help='script to run via pkgexec')
    parser.add_argument(...)
    cli_args = parser.parse_args()

    print(f'{__name__}: Running script {cli_args.script}')
    exec(open(cli_args.script).read(), globals(), globals())  # <-- ???
    print(f'{__name__}: Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

**The problem:** Nothing happens for `exec(open(cli_args.script).read())` (tried it with and without `, globals(), globals()`). The script is not executed. What am I doing wrong here?

Workarounds that I'm not keen on:

- I can run the script via `exec()` if I don't "install" the entry point. Not an option.
- I can run the script if I import it via `importlib`. But this is too restrictive for users of the package that are supposed to write a `main()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's *something* happening with the script's globals when calling `exec()`. I can't figure out what `runpy` from the standard library is doing differently, but it's certainly working. The solution in my case is to replace the `exec()` call with a call to `runpy.run_path()`.

Here is the modified `__main__.py` script for comparison:

```py
import argparse
import os
import runpy
import sys

from pkgexec import some_stuff

def main(args=None):
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('script', help='script to run via pkgexec')
    parser.add_argument(...)
    cli_args = parser.parse_args()

    print(f'{__name__}: Running script {cli_args.script}')
    mod = argparse.Namespace(
        **runpy.run_path(cli_args.script,
                         run_name=os.path.basename(cli_args.script)))
    print(f'{__name__}: Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

I'm sending the file name as `run_name` argument to `run_path` (this way the script "knows" its actual `__name__` instead of the default `<run_path>` set by `runpy`).

Note that this solution is only applicable if the script to run does **not** contain a `if __name__ == '__main__'` section (which is precisely what I wanted).

**UPDATE:** The same effect can be achieved by doing what `runpy` does under the hood: `compile()` the code first, then `exec()` it afterwards:

```py
# mod = argparse.Namespace(
#     **runpy.run_path(cli_args.script,
#                      run_name=os.path.basename(cli_args.script)))
code = compile(open(cli_args.script).read(),
               os.path.basename(cli_args.script), 
               'exec')
exec(code)
```